# How to specify different priveleges for different users in firebase?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I am designing an app in which some users need to have write access to the database while some can just read data. I am currently using google_sign_in for firebase authentication.
In my firestore rules I tried this:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read: if request.auth != null;
      allow write: if
          request.auth.token.email == 'test@test.com';
    }
  }
}
```

It doesn't work and I don't think its the right way.

Answer (score 1):

Those rules aren't Firestore rules.  They are Cloud Storage rules.  You can tell from the first line.  It says "firebase.storage".  Firestore rules would say "cloud.firestore".  You're either looking at the wrong product, or you've copied incorrect rules somehow.

Comment: I need to implement these rules for both firebase storage and cloud firestore so I tried these rules on both but they aren't working the way I want. Tell me if I'm missing something.

Comment: It's not possible to implement one set of rules for both.  They have to be done separately, according to the documentation for each product.

Comment: I am doing them separately in their own respective sections but even after applying the rules mentioned above I can write to database even if the email is not the one that I want to allow access to.

Comment: Also I want to allow several emails to be able to write to the database so the above approach doesn't seem to be good.